# get GraphUser from an opened session?

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm using the new Android Facebook SDK 3.0.

I'm implementing the login button in a dedicated activity which has the GraphUser with user details after the login process.

I want to know if there is any way to get the GraphUser object in another activity without a graph request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either create your own subclass of [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) with setters/getters for your GraphUser, and call set/get in your Activities, or you can do something like:

```
JsonObject jsonObj = graphUser.getInnerJsonObject();
String jsonString = jsonObj.toString();
```

in the caller activity, and put the jsonString in a bundle to be passed in the intent, then on the callee side, do something like:

```
String jsonString = bundle.getString("whatever_key_you_used");
JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject(jsonString);
GraphUser user = GraphObject.Factory.create(jsonObj, GraphUser.class);
```

Disclaimer: I just type out the above, so there may be syntax errors, and you may need to put a try/catch around `new JsonObject`.